# Web based radar animation using three.js/webgl

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl, css-transitions

I'm looking at implementing a web based animated radar visualisation and had a look at the rather simple implementations at [Radar scanner effect using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353107/radar-scanner-effect-using-jquery). The first version looked quite nice but was a real CPU hogger, while the pure CSS version was a bit too simple. How hard would it be to implement something similar to the first version using webgl for hardware acceleration, for example using three.js?

Another one I found which looks quite nice and actually is implemented on canvas: http://codepen.io/jackrugile/pen/wqLsn (had to paste code):

```
var radar = document.getElementById( 'radar' ), 
diameter = 220,
radius = diameter / 2,
padding = 14,
ctx = Sketch.create({
  container: radar,
  fullscreen: false,
  width: diameter,
  height: diameter
}),
dToR = function( degrees ){ 
  return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
},
sweepAngle = 270,
sweepSize = 2,
sweepSpeed = 1.2,
rings = 4,
hueStart = 120,
hueEnd = 170,
hueDiff = Math.abs( hueEnd - hueStart ),
saturation = 50,
lightness = 40,
lineWidth = 2,
gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient( radius, 0, 0, 0 );


radar.style.marginLeft = radar.style.marginTop = ( -diameter / 2 ) - padding + 'px';
gradient.addColorStop( 0, 'hsla( ' + hueStart + ', ' + saturation + '%, ' + lightness + '%, 1 )' );
gradient.addColorStop( 1, 'hsla( ' + hueEnd + ', ' + saturation + '%, ' + lightness + '%, 0.1 )' );

var renderRings = function(){
  var i;
  for( i = 0; i < rings; i++ ){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc( radius, radius, ( ( radius - ( lineWidth / 2) ) / rings) * ( i + 1 ), 0, TWO_PI, false );
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + ( hueEnd - ( i * ( hueDiff / rings ) ) ) + ', ' + saturation + '%, ' + lightness + '%, 0.1)';
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.stroke();
  };
};

var renderGrid = function(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo( radius - lineWidth / 2, lineWidth );
  ctx.lineTo( radius - lineWidth / 2, diameter - lineWidth );
  ctx.moveTo( lineWidth, radius - lineWidth / 2 );
  ctx.lineTo( diameter - lineWidth, radius - lineWidth / 2 );
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla( ' + ( ( hueStart + hueEnd ) / 2) + ', ' + saturation + '%, ' + lightness + '%, .03 )';
  ctx.stroke();
};

var renderSweep = function(){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate( radius, radius );
  ctx.rotate( dToR(sweepAngle) );  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo( 0, 0 );
  ctx.arc( 0, 0, radius, dToR( -sweepSize ), dToR( sweepSize ), false );
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fill();  
  ctx.restore();
};

var renderScanLines = function(){
  var i;
  var j;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for( i = 0; i < diameter; i += 2 ){    
    ctx.moveTo( 0, i + .5 );
    ctx.lineTo( diameter, i + .5);
  };
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla( 0, 0%, 0%, .02 )';
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.stroke();
};

ctx.clear = function(){
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'hsla( 0, 0%, 0%, 0.1 )';
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, diameter, diameter );
};

ctx.update = function(){
  sweepAngle += sweepSpeed;
};

ctx.draw = function(){
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
  renderRings();
  renderGrid();
  renderSweep();
  renderScanLines();
};
```

It's also is a bit heavy on the CPU though.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it is to draw 2 sprites, one is the base image of the radar and the other is the sweeping line. Then just rotate the sweeping line sprite every frame and that should do it.

Comment: I agree with WacławJasper, a couple of images and rotation should do it. But if you really want to get the GPU involved you could write a shader such as [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdsXRf) or [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4s2SRt). No real need for three.js if you want it in 2D